# Creating a dataframe with vector entries

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, vector, formula

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe where the entry in a single cell is a numpy array. For example, given a list of chemical compounds - A2B3C4, D1A2J3 etc, I create a numpy array for each of them so that:

```
firstium - A2B3C4 - [2,3,4,0,0,0,0.....]

secondium - D1A2J3 - [2,0,0,1,......3....]
```

I would like to create a dataframe with just two columns - 'name' and 'vec' where name is the string for the name of the compound and vec has the array for the formula. let's say that vec is of dimension 1 x 100.

```
 Name             vec
firstium          [2,3,4,0,0,0...]
secondium         [2,0,0,1,.....3.]
```

etc.

What I have been doing so far is to create a dictinary {'name':'vec'} and converting this to a dataframe:

```
 Min_dict={}

 for ....:
    ..
    Min_dict[min_name]=vec

 Min_Dataframe=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Min_dict,orient='index')
```

However, this gives me a dataframe with as many columns as the dimension of the array, plus one. So, my dataframe has dimensions data x 101.  I need it to be data x 2

This makes it inconvenient to do processing on the data as I would like to treat each array as one unit of information. Does any one know how to do what I just described?

Thanks!

Comment: A cell of a DataFrame can't hold data unless you specify its `dtype` to be `object`, which is not recommended. There must be a better way. For example using `multiindex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

### Setup

```
data = {
    'firstium': np.array([2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]),
    'secondium': np.array([2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3])
}
```

---

### Option 1

```
pd.Series(data).rename_axis('Name').reset_index(name='Vec')

        Name                 Vec
0   firstium  [2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
1  secondium  [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]
```

---

### Option 2

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(('Name', 'Vec'), zip(*data.items()))))

        Name                 Vec
0   firstium  [2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
1  secondium  [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3]
```